# When the Sony Reader Store moves to Kobo will Kobo begin showing DRM?

Tags: drm, kobo-store, sony

Rather disappointing discovery.  I just made my first purchase from the Sony Reader Store https://ebookstore.sony.com because a series of books I was looking for could only be found there without DRM.  The books were clearly marked '[DRM-free EPUB](https://ebookstore.sony.com/ebook/philip-jose-farmer/riverworld/_/R-400000000000000211899)' and when I purchased and downloaded the books Calibre had no problem converting them to Mobi so I could read them on my kindle. ([*Found with Calibre also*](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/891/are-there-any-ebook-search-engines/892#892))

The bad news is there is huge header on the page, "**Closing March 20, 2014. we will transition customers to Kobo.**" [details](https://blog.sony.com/2014/02/the-future-of-reader-store/) seem to indicate that accounts will be transferred, but there is no indication that the clarity of DRM status will be transferred over. As we know from [this question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/851) Kobo does not have a good record of being forth coming about DRM status.

Is there any indication that Kobo will embrace any of the business model (like declaring DRM) from the Sony Reader Store, or will they just absorb the accounts?

Comment: FYI The announced this move on Feb 6th with an email to customers. As I understand it you **have to actively opt out** if you don't want your data moved to the Kobo company, the email included a link for that.

Comment: This question is probably best mailed to the involved; I don't think any third party can answer with confidence.

Comment: @Raphael, my expectation would be some kind of public information release of details.  If they have not made a change of this type public, you would not expect a random question to the help desk to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: In both cases, I don't see how an SE question is appropriate/helpful.